# Error while uploading zip file to lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I tried uploading code as a zip file to AWS Lambda, but it's throwing an error: " unhandled error reporting in developer mode only. check the console logs for details. message: cannot read property 'renderer' of null".

Comment: Check your code for property `renderer` and make sure it is not `null`. The error message already written for you.

Comment: How are you uploading your Lambda code? AWS Lambda Console? AWSCLI? What is the exact error (please copy/paste, don't write it out). Is this Node.js, Python, something else?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem.
The uploaded the zip which contains code and library packages is conflicting with existing lambda code and package structure.

Just refresh the page then your problem will be solved